# How can I delete a Tkinter label without binding it to a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

My program has a temporary label that needs to be removed when the user types in the first correct answer because a new label is supposed to replace the initial one.
I tried using the "destroy" method without success.

Can someone help me remove the "score_label" inside the "check" function?

```py
def check(text:tkinter.Text, event=None):

    global remove_label
    global eq 
    global score
    global q_num
    global current_stage
    
    ans = calc(eq)

    print(f"real answear = {ans}")
    temp = str(text.get("0.0", "end").strip())
    print(f"my answear = {temp}")

    if str(text.get("0.0", "end").strip()) == str(ans):
         is_correct = True
         remove_label += 1

    else:
         is_correct = False

    if is_correct:
        score += 10
        q_num += 1
        inputtxt.delete(1.0,END)

        eq = generate_equation(stage=current_stage)

        score_label    = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"score: {score}",font=my_font,fg="white",bg='#08241c')       .grid(row=2, column=2,sticky=W)
        question_label = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"{q_num}: {eq}",font=my_font,fg="white",bg='#08241c')        .grid(row=2, column=5,sticky=W)
        stage_label    = tkinter.Label(master=master,text=f"Stage: {current_stage}",font=my_font,fg="white",bg='#08241c').grid(row=2, column=3,sticky=W)
        inputtxt.grid(row=3,column=4,sticky=W,ANCHOR=CENTER)


        if score % 100 == 0:
            current_stage += 1

    else:
        inputtxt.grid(row=3,column=4,sticky=W)

    
master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Math")
master.geometry('800x569')

background_image=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\guyzv\\Desktop\\New folder\\greenboard.png")
background_label = tkinter.Label(master, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

eq  = generate_equation(stage=current_stage)
ans = calc(eq)

my_font = tkFont.Font(family="Bradley Hand ITC", size=30)

score_label    = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"score: {score}",font=my_font,fg="white",bg='#08241c').grid(row=2, column=2,sticky=W)
question_label = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"{q_num}: {eq}",font=my_font,fg="white",bg='#08241c').grid(row=2, column=5,sticky=W)
stage_label    = tkinter.Label(master = master,text=f"Stage: {current_stage}",font=my_font,fg="white",bg='#08241c').grid(row=2, column= 3,sticky=W)
inputtxt       = tkinter.Text(master=master, height=1, width=10,font=my_font,fg="white",bg='#08241c')

inputtxt.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda ev: check(inputtxt,ev))

inputtxt.grid(row=3,column=4,sticky=W)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: `score_label.destroy()` also why do you need to destroy it? can't you just reconfigure it? also please provide a [mre]

Comment: Do you notice that `score_label` is None because it is the result of `.grid(...)`?

Comment: You haven't declared `score_label` as a `global` in the `check()` function, so you're creating and referencing a local variable that has that name within it. I *strongly* suggest you learn how to define and use classes to avoid creating messes of global variables the way you are now doing. See [Global variables are bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: If you're wanting to destroy it just to replace it with another, you should reconsider. The simpler solution is to simply change the text on the existing label.

Comment: You cannot pack a widget in a variable. You did it like this: ```label = Label(root).pack()``` which returns ```None```